# libgdx rectangle around actor

Tags: java, libgdx, bounding-box, rect

How does one draw a `Rectangle` around an `Actor` with a given `Texture`? The `Rectangle` should scale, move and rotate along with the `Actor`.
Current implementation:

```
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line); 
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED); 
Vector2 _BL = localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(getX(), getY()));
Vector2 _BR = localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(getX() + getWidth(), getY()));
Vector2 _TL = localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(getX(), getY() + getHeight()));
Vector2 _TR = localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(getX() + getWidth(), getY() + getHeight()));
float xmin = MyMathUtils.min(_BL.x, _BR.x, _TL.x, _TR.x);
float ymin = MyMathUtils.min(_BL.y, _BR.y, _TL.y, _TR.y);
float xmax = MyMathUtils.max(_BL.x, _BR.x, _TL.x, _TR.x);
float ymax = MyMathUtils.max(_BL.y, _BR.y, _TL.y, _TR.y);
shapeRenderer.rect(xmin, ymin, xmax-xmin, ymax-ymin);
shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
shapeRenderer.circle(_BL.x, _BL.y, 2);
shapeRenderer.circle(_BR.x, _BR.y, 2);
shapeRenderer.circle(_TL.x, _TL.y, 2);
shapeRenderer.circle(_TR.x, _TR.y, 2);
shapeRenderer.end();
```

The problem is that `Rectangle` doesn't fit well after moving the `Actor`. I think it has to do with a bad `Coordinate Transformation`.

I would like to do something like this:

```
Matix4 m = actor.computeTransform();
shapeRenderer.setTransformMatrix(m);
```

but the *computeTransform()* is available in `Group` (which is an `Actor`), but not in `Actor` itself.

Comment: Are you using `Scene2D` cause you are talking about `Actor`s? If you are, you could use `Group` and add the 2 `Actor`s (your Actor and the Rectangle, if the Rectangle has some functions to). Otherwise you could draw the Rectangle in the `actor.draw(delta)` method. There you have the position and size of your actor.

Comment: Just to mention... Don't use the new Statement every frame. You create 4x60 new Vectors every second.. The GC will slow down your game by collecting the unused ones.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?